# What is the runtime complexity of array slicing in C# with Index/Range?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

In C#, there are at least two different ways of "slicing" an array.  One can use Linq's `Skip()` and `Take()` methods (which work on other collection types too), as follows...

`myArr.Skip(10).Take(20);`

...or one can use the new `System.Index` and `System.Range` types:

`myArr[10..20]`

Does range indexing offer a performance improvement over Skip/Take, assuming the underlying collection in either case is an indexable/materialized one such as `Array` or `List<T>`?

Comment: "We know that the Linq method that the entire collection be iterated" - citation needed. (You obviously know that most LINQ methods have special code for arrays/lists... so that statement is confusing and need an official link as confirmation)

Comment: *"We know that the Linq method that the entire collection be iterated"* - This isn't always true, and assuming `myArr` really is an array, it's definitely false. If the source implements `IList<T>`, as arrays do, the internals use `ListPartition<T>`, which simply takes start index. Calling `Take` on that further refines the window with a new `ListPartition<T>`. `ListPartition<T>` is LINQ's way of doing `Span`-like things when it can avoid enumeration. It's internal so you don't normally see it.

Comment: Interesting!  I guess I should do more extensive research before posting questions.   So Skip() and Take(), when used on an indexable collection, can indeed reap the performance benefits of range indexing?  Thus, if one wanted to continually slice the collection (as in a recursive/divide-and-conquer operation that acts on fewer and fewer elements with each call), the performance would be roughly the same as using Index/Range (save for the need to call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on the `IEnumerable` results of `Take()` each time it's called).

Comment: If you were to "continually slice the collection" for that, I'd just use spans and avoid the allocations you get from slicing an array.

Answer (score 0):

A call to `Take<T>(int)` will end up in this implementation:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count)
        {
            return
                source is IPartition<TSource> partition ? partition.Take(count) :
                source is IList<TSource> sourceList ? new ListPartition<TSource>(sourceList, 0, count - 1) :
                new EnumerablePartition<TSource>(source, 0, count - 1);
        }
```

One can dig deeper, but in the end it's obvious that when using `ListPartition<T>` for List or an array, both Take and Skip are O(1), which is what one would expect. It requires the allocation of a temporary iterator instance, but the data is not copied.

The implementation for `EnumerablePartition<T>` is a bit more complex and hence the iteration over it is in the worst case O(n) per step, but it also does not create a copy of the data.

On the other hand, if you do

```cs
int[] data = new data[30];
int[] result = data[10..20];
```

this is internally converted to a call to `T[] RuntimeHelpers.GetSubArray<T>(T[] array, Range range)`. Already from the signature, one can see that this creates a copy of the array segment. Note that the range operator is (for whatever reason) only supported on arrays, not on IList, unlike the Linq operators.